# Selecting an element and anything inside it

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a click event and an if statement within that as shown below.

```
if (!$(e.target).is("textarea.textobject, div.texteditor"))
{
  // do stuff
}
```

It works but the problem is the div shown below. When I click on either the span or table inside the div it doesn't work. I have tried (div.texteditor > *) but that doesn't work.

```
<div class="texteditor">
   <span>1</span>
   <table>
      <tr><td></td></tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

So basically I want to be able to select div.texteditor and it to encompass everything inside it. Does anyone know a solution to this? I'm sure i'm missing something..

Comment: Can you show where this `if` statement is running?

Answer (score 0):

If the event handler is on the `<div>` itself, just use `this` instead of `e.target` (which may be a child), like this:

```
if (!$(this).is("textarea.textobject, div.texteditor"))
{
  // do stuff
}
```

...if instead you want to check if the target is anywhere inside one of those 2 selector types, use [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) and [`.length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/), like this:

```
if ($(e.target).closest("textarea.textobject, div.texteditor").length == 0)
{
  // do stuff
}
```

Since [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) works on the current elements *and* parents, it's pretty handy here.

Comment: It needs to have e.target. Actually I might have solved it myself.

This seems to work.
if (!$(e.target).is("textarea.textobject, div.texteditor, div.texteditor *"))

It selects div.texteditor and then div.texteditor with anything inside it.

Comment: @codemonkey - that can work, check out the `.closest()` solution above though, it'll do the same thing more efficiently :)

Comment: I understand what it does and I have tried your solution but it didn't work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, but have you tried to create another events assigned to the elements inside the div?
Something like:

```
if ( $(e.target).is("span") &&  $(e.target).parent("div.texteditor") )
{
  // do stuff
}
```

I don't if it works, but it's an idea!

I hope it helps you. ^^

If you want to apply to all children, this could work:

```
if ( $(e.target).parent("div.texteditor") )
{
  // do stuff
}
```

Comment: That might work but I needed a 'catch all' because the elements in the div might change.